# How to generate random number by given string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As `hash` function gives different values in different python interpreters , Is there a more stable one in python ?

Update one:

"stable" means that the function should give the same number when the string is same anytime. `hash` can't do it .

I want a function like :

```
def generate_random_number_by_string(string:str)->int:
    pass
```

For example , `generate_random_number_by_string("16")` should be the same in anytime .

Comment: Can you define "stable"? Why does this matter to your application?

Comment: Hi , @ggorlen . "stable" means that the function should give the same number when the string is same anytime. ```hash``` can't do it .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a hash from `hashlib`.  For example:

```py
import hashlib
int(hashlib.sha256(b'yourstring').hexdigest(), base=16)
```

Comment: @DachuanZhao Yes, sha256 hash gives totally uniform distribution of its value.

Comment: @DachuanZhao Code above gives uniform distribution of integers in range from 0 to 2^256-1.

Comment: @Arty It's enough . Thanks very much ~~~